# Split a Multisite Into Single WordPress Websites

Tags: multisite, wordpress-version

I am using wordpress export/import feature to slpit a multi site into single wordpress site. It is exported all the post but not extract the user. How can I export the user.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: AFAICR all of the users live in the first site of the network, i.e. the one with blogid=1. Can you export that site then graft the users from that export into your other site's export?

Comment: A quick [Google search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=wordpress+user+export+import) led me to the [Cimy User Manager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/cimy-user-manager/) plugin. Is that something like what you need? **Caveat:** I've never used this plugin, and I don't endorse it in any way.